# Tikz - Vertical Position Unchanged

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, itemize, tikz-trees

I would like to have the  graph

```
\begin{itemize}
\item
$
\tikz {
  \node (a) at (-0.3,-2) [] {U};
\node (b) at (1,-2) [] {V};
\node (c) at (2,-2) [] {W};
\draw (a) edge[left,->] node[above] {$a_1$} (b) (b) edge[->] node[above] {$a_2$} (c);
\draw (a) edge[bend right,<-] node[below right] {$a_3$} (b);
\draw (a.south) edge[bend right=60,<-] node[below right] {$k_4$} (c);
}
$ 
\end{itemize}
```

in such a way that the line defined by the bottom of the letters $U,V,W$ is
an horizontal line passing through the "bullet" of my item.

I tried to put -2 as y-coordinates but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the `baseline` key is for. I also add an alternative using `positioning` instead of absolute coordinates.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item
\tikz[baseline={(a.base)}] {
  \node (a) at (-0.3,-2) [] {U};
\node (b) at (1,-2) [] {V};
\node (c) at (2,-2) [] {W};
\draw (a) edge[left,->] node[above] {$a_1$} (b) (b) edge[->] node[above] {$a_2$} (c);
\draw (a) edge[bend right,<-] node[below right] {$a_3$} (b);
\draw (a.south) edge[bend right=60,<-] node[below right] {$k_4$} (c);
}
\item
\tikz[baseline={(a.base)},node distance=6mm] {
  \node (a) {U};
\node[right=of a] (b) {V};
\node[right=of b] (c) {W};
\draw (a) edge[left,->] node[above] {$a_1$} (b) (b) edge[->] node[above] {$a_2$} (c);
\draw (a) edge[bend right,<-] node[below right] {$a_3$} (b);
\draw (a.south) edge[bend right=60,<-] node[below right] {$k_4$} (c);
}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

your graph is simpler to draw with `tikz-cd`. it is positioned on item baseline:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
\item   \begin{tikzcd}
        U \ar[r,"a_1"]
            & V \ar[l,bend left,"a_3"] \ar[r,"a_2"]
                & W\ar[ll,bend left=60,"k_4"]
        \end{tikzcd}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]